# paste pop up disappears in safari (iPad with iOS 8.0.2) when a label in html is changed

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

I have developed a web page and this page contains a label that gets updated every second (to display the time). And the same page also has a text box for taking the user input.

The problem I am facing is, I am viewing this page in safari browser in iPad (with iOS version 8.0.2), and trying to paste some content into the text box. However, strangely the paste pop up disappears within a second. When I debugged, I got to know this pop up disappears when the time (on the label) is updated (and that happens once in a second). To confirm this, I delayed the time update (in turn updating the label) to once in a minute and I noticed, the paste pop up remained for a minute and disappeared as soon as the time is updated.

I did the same experiment using iPad with iOS version 7.1.2, the above mentioned problem is not observed.

I wanted to know why this happens, is it expected of iOS 8.0.2? Any information on this is helpful.

I am also copying my code here for better understanding of what am I doing.

HTML:

```
Time: <label id="time"></label><br/><br/>
Input the content: <input type="text" value=""/>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload=function()
{
    updateTime();
}

function updateTime()
{
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
    setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any animations or transitions?

I was having the same issue until I took out a ".no-js" CSS transition that was happening infinitely every one second... Check your animations, iOS 8 closes their pop-ups any time a website does an animation or a transition.